# Magento2.2.1 crashes half way through 7000 products import, with 500 Internal server error on form key request

Tags: magento-2.2.1

With a brand new installation of Magento 2.2.1 on PHP 7.1, all settings correct (I believe), I use System/Import to put in 7000 products. And the page hangs with spinning loader. On re-importing I looked at the browser network console and found this internal server error:

```
Request URL:http://www.myUrl.co.uk/myAdminUrl/admin/import/start/key/my Key/&form_key=myFormKey
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:myip
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

shouldn't this ampersand be a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please change execution time from server or use magmi to product import if you have more products in magento2.

Thanks
```

Comment: I'm not sure if http://www.myUrl.co.uk/myAdminUrl/admin/import/start/key/my Key/&form_key=myFormKey is a valid http request. I thought I had found a bug.